# Is there a TzScan API to find the total number of delegated Tezos?

Tags: delegating, tzscan, api, javascript

I'm looking for an API to get the total number of delegated Tezos.

I already found an API to get the number of rolls delegated:
https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/rolls_history/tz1Pv7ha8wzAyRHkR9RahWapdopK1tt6nVz1?number=1

But I'm not able to find the total number of delegated Tezos.